# SendData is not abstract and does not override abstract method returnData(byte[],byte) in ReceivedDataListener

Tags: android

I have a bit of an issue with some code and need some help!

I am getting the following error on this line of code:

```
public class SendData implements ReceivedDataListener {
```

The error is

> Error:(16, 8) error: SendData is not abstract and does not override
>   abstract method returnData(byte[],byte) in ReceivedDataListener

My code for ReceivedDataListener looks like this:

```
package com.commandsoftware.androidbookingapp.Services.Communications;

public interface ReceivedDataListener {
    void returnData(byte[] incomingData, byte commsIdentifier);
}
```

SendData looks like this:

```
package com.commandsoftware.androidbookingapp.Services.Communications;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;

import com.commandsoftware.androidbookingapp.Services.Communications.ReceivedDataListener;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Anthony on 29/07/2014.
 */
public class SendData implements ReceivedDataListener {

    public static byte[] stringToData(String str, byte varID) {
        int strLength = str.length();
        byte[] varData = new byte[strLength];
        byte[] varHeader = new byte[]
                { varID, (byte) (strLength & 0xff) };
        try
        {
            varData = str.getBytes("ASCII");
        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        byte[] message = new byte[varHeader.length + varData.length];
        System.arraycopy(varHeader, 0, message, 0, varHeader.length);
        System.arraycopy(varData, 0, message, varHeader.length, varData.length);
        return message;
    }

    public static byte[] intToData(int number, byte varID, int varLength) {
        byte[] message = new byte[varLength + 2];
        message[0] = varID;
        message[1] = (byte) (varLength & 0xff);
        switch (varLength)
        {
            case ProcessData.ONE_BYTE:
                message[2] = (byte) (number & 0xff);
                break;
            case ProcessData.TWO_BYTES:
                message[2] = (byte) (number >> 8);
                message[3] = (byte) (number & 0xff);
                break;
            case ProcessData.FOUR_BYTES:
                message[2] = (byte) (number >> 24);
                message[3] = (byte) (number >> 16);
                message[4] = (byte) (number >> 8);
                message[5] = (byte) (number & 0xff);
                break;
        }
        return message;
    }

    public static byte[] calculateLength(byte[] message, int noVariables) {
        int packetLen = message.length;
        byte[] lengthBytes =
                { (byte) (packetLen >> 8), (byte) (packetLen & 0xff), (byte) (noVariables & 0xff) };
        return lengthBytes;
    }

    public static byte[] calculateChecksum(byte[] message) {
        int val = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < message.length; i++)
        {
            val += (message[i] & 0xff);
        }
        int mod = val % 65536;
        byte[] checksumBytes =
                { (byte) (mod >> 8), (byte) (mod & 0xff) };
        return checksumBytes;
    }

    public static byte[] addHeaders(ArrayList<byte[]> array, byte headerByte) {
        // splitting back ArrayList into bytes
        int sum = 0;
        for (byte[] ba : array)
        {
            sum = sum + ba.length;
        }

        byte[] finalbuf = new byte[sum];
        int curpos = 0;
        for (byte[] ba : array)
        {
            System.arraycopy(ba, 0, finalbuf, curpos, ba.length);
            curpos = curpos + ba.length;
        }

        byte[] lengthBytes = calculateLength(finalbuf, array.size() - 1);
        byte[] messageWithLen = Comms.bytesAppend(lengthBytes, finalbuf);
        byte[] chkSumBytes = calculateChecksum(messageWithLen);
        byte[] messageWithCkSum = Comms.bytesAppend(chkSumBytes, messageWithLen);
        byte[] header =
                { (byte) 0xaa, (byte) 0xcc, (byte) 0x88, headerByte };
        byte[] finalMessage = Comms.bytesAppend(header, messageWithCkSum);

        StringBuilder sentBytes = new StringBuilder();
        for (byte cha : finalMessage)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = Comms.byteToText(cha);
            sentBytes.append(sb);
        }
        return finalMessage;
    }


    public void CalculateFare(int FromEasting, int FromNorthing, int ToEasting, int ToNorthing, Activity callingActivity, final Context ctx)
    {
        ArrayList<byte[]> fareByteArrays = new ArrayList<byte[]>();
        // from X
        byte[] data1 = intToData(FromEasting, (byte) 0x01, 4);
        fareByteArrays.add(data1);

        // from Y
        byte[] data2 = intToData(FromNorthing, (byte) 0x02, 4);
        fareByteArrays.add(data2);

        // to X
        byte[] data3 = intToData(ToEasting, (byte) 0x03, 4);
        fareByteArrays.add(data3);

        // to Y
        byte[] data4 = intToData(ToNorthing, (byte) 0x04, 4);
        fareByteArrays.add(data4);

        // vehicletype
        byte[] data5 = stringToData("0", (byte) 0x05);
        fareByteArrays.add(data5);

        // add ff
        byte[] data6 =
                { (byte) 0xff };
        fareByteArrays.add(data6);

        byte[] finalFareMessage = addHeaders(fareByteArrays, (byte) 0xf1);
        Comms conn = new Comms(finalFareMessage, callingActivity, ctx);
        conn.startLongRunningOperation();
    }
}
```

Not too sure if this is relevant but here is my android manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.commandsoftware.androidbookingapp" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Many thanks for your help in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide an implementation for `void returnData(byte[] incomingData, byte commsIdentifier)` in your SendData class because you are implementing the interface.

Add the following to your SendData class

```
@Override
public void returnData(byte[] incomingData, byte commsIdentifier) {
    // Your implementation goes here
}
```

Comment: I shall do this now, however I do believe you are correct, I will add the required code and then let you know, many thanks.

Comment: No problem at all, glad it helped you out. I don't know what IDE you are using but if you use some modern ones like Netbeans, Eclipse or IntelliJ they actually give you nice hints on what to do when problems occur... check it out :) Happy coding!

Comment: I have just started using Android Studio, after coming from Eclipse, The hints are generally very useful however not this time. Ah well, I have learnt from my mistake and will remember next time :)